# Audio goes a frame or two out of sync after export premier pro

Tags: video, premiere, sync

i've finished my film and i'm trying to export my film in 1080p 23.976 fps , using h.264 audio acc 44.100 khz and 192 bit rate .

when i export my full film my audio is slightly out of sync/time with video. when i only export small portion of the film with exact same settings the audio is back in time and everything seems in sync again ?  please help me you wonderful people yes ?  ;-)  my film is 45 minutes long

the portion i exported was about 1.30 mins , i have tried many different settings including higher fps 29.976 etc but still the same thing happens out of sync on full film, and ok in small portion export !

and i'm exporting the same portion and referencing that one segment !

last attempt i'm currently making is from another forums advice is deleting render files before export ? i'm still don't know if this has worked as i'm waiting for export to finish !  anyone can help me out , thanks alot , Dave >

Comment: What's the source footage framerate?

Comment: it is 24 fps footage shot at 1080 p using a 5 d mk3 canon , my sequence settings are 1080p hd 23.976 fps , and i have tried different export settings but mainly the same export settings as the sequence settings !

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to framerate problems.There are two types of 24 fps.
"True" 24 fps and 23.98 FPS.
This mostly doesn't make any issues, but stretched over a longer time, this can change the video duration. For a 45min video, this makes 64800 frames, instead of 64746.
This gives a difference if about 2.25 seconds.

After trying to delete the pre-rendered files as you said before, try to change the sequenze settings.
**Before you do this, MAKE A COPY!**

If this doesn't help, another way would be to try another codec and or container. So try h.265 or HDx or avi... It may be that those codecs don't have these problem

Comment: What's with the quotes around "true"? Is it not actually the true 24FPS, so it's "fake true"? What do you mean

Comment: @MikeA.Christensen there is two different frame rates described as 24 fps.  There is 24fps and 23.976fps (otherwise known as 24fps drop frame)  This is an artifact of how color information was encoded in the space that used to be taken up by a frame of video back in the day and still hangs around now.  24fps is an odd one since it wasn't a broadcast spec prior to digital, but it still has a drop frame specification in addition to the non-drop frame that actually has exactly 24 frames per second.